# bash - invalid JSON when curling to Heroku

Tags: javascript, bash, heroku

I'm writing my first bash script, attempting to set a Heroku environment variable via a `curl`. However, I'm getting a bad request error from Heroku, saying that my data is invalid JSON. I don't understand why, though.

First off, my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

GIT_COMMIT=`node get_git_commit.js`

echo $GIT_COMMIT

curl -n -X PATCH https://api.heroku.com/apps/my-app-name/config-vars \
  -d '{
  "GIT_COMMIT": $GIT_COMMIT
}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

This script references JavaScript file, `get_git_commit.js`:

```
const fs = require("fs")

require("child_process").exec("git rev-parse HEAD", (err, stdout) => {
    const commit = stdout.replace(/\n/g, "")
    console.log(`"${commit}"`)
}
```

When I run the bash script, the `echo` correctly prints the git hash to the console, but Heroku returns

```
{
    "id":"bad_request",
    "message":"Provided data is invalid JSON."
}
```

I tested just manually setting the data as

```
"GIT_COMMIT": 1234
```

and that worked perfectly.

I'm totally new to writing for bash, so maybe there are some basic conventions that I'm missing - any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SLaks noted, this was a quotation issue.  Although I was preparing the git commit hash string with double-quotes, it needed an additional single-quote wrapper in the bash script -

```
"GIT_COMMIT": "'"$GIT_COMMIT"'"
```

That did it!

Answer (score 1):

`$GIT_COMMIT` probably isn't a number.

You're probably sending something like `{ "GIT_COMMIT": 4d2fb }`, which is not valid JSON.

You need to wrap strings in quotes.

Comment: You're definitely right (I forgot that the hash wouldn't be strictly numeric) and I did try wrapping the `$GIT_COMMIT` in quotes - `console.log(`"${stdout}"`)` in the JS file - but that still produced the same error (the `echo` included the quotes).

Comment: What is the exact request body?